# GitHub noobian, should I install msysGit or Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, github, cygwin, msysgit, git-extensions

I intend to use [GitHub](http://github.com) with [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) and possibly integrate with FogBugz (optional).

Looking at the [download page](http://git-scm.com/download) and reading some rather technical half related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690502/can-i-use-msysgit-and-cygwins-git) I wanted to see what you thought would be better to install on Windows 7, given I want to integrate with Visual Studio 2008 (thinking this would be through GitExtensions).

A straight answer (msysGit or Cygwin?) between the two would be great but any more no brainer advice on starting out on GitHub would be welcome, or if indeed I've missed the mark entirely (does it matter which?).  Will be importing from Subversion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never found the previous options that great for Windows and had used mercurial for quite some time instead.

Now GitHub have done [github:windows](http://windows.github.com/) and after just a little use it is very impressive.  It's a well thought out product and think will greatly extend GitHub usage on windows.

Answer (score 7):

Cygwin's was the officially recommended one last time I checked, but I think msysgit might have caught up now.  I'm using TortoiseGit with msysgit, and it seems to work fine.  Recommended.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Cygwin is much better: [Windows Git Tutorial: Cygwin, SSH and Projectlocker](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/09/windows-git-tutorial-cygwin-ssh-and.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you used TortoiseSVN with Subversion you might want to take a look at [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/), TortoiseSVN's Git version.

Answer (score 2):

**Git Extensions requires msysGit**. The "Complete" installation has msysGit and KDiff3 packed with it.

As for the versus, the only major difference I know of is that msysGit doesn't support `git-daemon`, yet. Since you're using GitHub, this shouldn't affect you much.