# Distributing git configuration with the code

Tags: git

In trying to standardise the platform for the developers, one of my needs would be to commit the `.git/config` so that everybody have the same CRLF config without forgetting to set it by hand.

How do I set this up?

I'm a bit concerned by all this negativity against `autocrlf`. Why not remove this feature if it doesn't work? Either the makers of this feature are misunderstood or they made a failed experiment with it and it should be removed to stop more people from wasting their time (reading the obscure man page, asking questions, people answering those questions etc.).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332349/best-practices-for-cross-platform-git-config: you may have an answer to add to this similar question.

Comment: thanks, but I'm a bit concerned by all this negativity against autocrlf, why not remove this feature if it doesn't work? Either the makers of this feature are misunderstood or they made a failed experiment with it and it should be removed to stop more people from wasting their time (reading the obscure man page, asking questions, people answering those questions etc.)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I have always found the `autocrlf` config property problematic.
(as expressed in my answer [Git 1.6.4 beta on Windows (msysgit) - Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination/1250133#1250133))

- it not only make [some merges tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598709/git-cygwin-trailing-whitespace-causes-not-uptodate/1598962#1598962)
- it can vary [depending on the shell used within one environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690502/can-i-use-msysgit-and-cygwins-git/690747#690747)
- it also has issue with [git status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them)
- and with [svn import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042207/git-svn-rebase-fails/1042597#1042597).

Note: [msysgit issue 538](https://groups.google.com/g/msysgit/c/XRamZGAOHeo/m/Qo3igUIGdBcJ) advocated for setting it to false by default, instead of true (which is the default value set by the [msysgit installer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100801032457/http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) of the time -- 2010!), but I am not convinced.

I would prefer one of the three following solutions for:

- configuring one end-of-line style
- making that configuration propagate through the different Git repos

First: `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
Then:

1. Using the new [config setting **`core.eol`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operati/3209806#3209806) (1.7.2+)

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the text property set.
> Alternatives are '`lf`', '`crlf`' and '`native`', which uses the platform's native line ending.
> The default value is native.

2. a [checkout/checking `.gitattribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206406/dealing-with-files-that-git-refuses-to-reset/1206441#1206441).
See [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) man page:
`crlf` or `core.autocrlf` is the way to record in a `.gitattributes` file what is was previously a local config attribute.

You can add [checkout/checkin attributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in) like:

```
*.vcproj    text eol=crlf
*.sh        text eol=lf
```

3. a [git attribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) which can:

- enforce any kind of formatting standard you may want to set
- apply those standards to certain files/directories
- be recorded as a config file (`.gitattributes`) able to be pushed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I get confused messages regarding autocrlf. I've read somewhere that git does commit only in \n mode and that it's good. some of my developers are using windows, and since everybody in the world can read crlf, I just think crlf for everybody is the best. BUT we have to accomodate git who seems to only like cr. What do you think ?
I'm reviewing the attribute idea, I ruled it out before because my understanding was that it applies works on a per file basis, not repository-wide. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @narynaud: personally, I like '`\n`', and I like not changing anyhting regarding eol. But should you enforce one eol style, `.gitattributes` is really interesting because you can apply it to the all repository, or only to specific parts within the repo.

Comment: If I define 
* +crlf
at the project root, I suppose I'm going to hell with my png pictures ?
How can I say "if you think it's text then do crlf otherwise, do binary". I'd like to avoid making the hard decision by myself, the system is good at this guessing and debugging an error would be really difficult.

Comment: @nraynaud: `*.png -crlf` placed *after* `* +crlf` (in the same `.gitattributes` file) should take care of that.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. because I'll forget to add the .gif or one day one co-worker will add a new file format and don't see he destroyed it at the commit ("it worked on my computer", and tests don't see visual destruction of a website).
To me it looks like this is digging in a bad solution.

Comment: @nraynaud: right, so why don't you make the opposite and only specify the specific types where you *need* an auto-conversion, leaving all the other untouched? The idea remains: you can specify some kind of format standard in a `.gitattributes` file (pushed/pulled), as opposed to local config settings.

Comment: I think it's the same problem on the "textfile" side. I wonder if I shouldn't ditch CRLF alltogether, but I don't really know how the Windows editors will react.

Comment: BTW I give you the points, I think that you're the closest from a solution. It looks like what I would really need is a patch to be committed into git.

Comment: @nraynaud: "I think it's the same problem on the "textfile" side": not quite, as a new text type not taken into your account wouldn't trigger a "destruction" of its content.  "I wonder if I shouldn't ditch CRLF alltogether": I sure did ;) And all of my recent Windows editor (Notepad++, Scite, EditPad Pro, ...) deal with those files just fine.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. However, I have a question about how you would implement it. Say I wanted to get enforce the lf encoding on only .rb files, how would I configure my .git/config file and the project root .gitattributes file? Wouldn't it work if .git/config had `core.autocrlf = false` and .gitattributes has `*.rb text`?

Comment: @vrish88: I am not sure because I haven't tested it directly, nut that is the general idea. Note: `text` means it will follow the `core.eol` configuration variable for all text files (in your `.git/config`).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a Unix family operating system I would recommend just creating a symbolic link.

```
ln -s .git/config git-config
git add git-config
git commit -m "Now tracking git config file"
```

Comment: That's a smart idea, we have mixed Windows/Mac/linux. But maybe git can use the windows link stuff, I'll try to google that.

Comment: it doesn't work, on unix git doesn't sees the changes to the configuration file even with the link.

Comment: Well if you're on unix it should work the other way around

 mv .git/config git-config;
 cd .git;
 ln -s ../git-config config;
cd ..;
git add git-config;
git commit -m "Now tracking git config file";

Answer (score 3):

The `.git/config` can be overridden locally by `~/.gitconfig`.

So as part of the build, Makefile or provision script, you can propose the change for users into their `~/.gitconfig`, or load local script `.gitconfig` via `git config`.

For example, create new `.gitconfig` with some settings, and load it by:

```
git config --local include.path "/path/to/.gitconfig"
```

or ask users to have in their `~/.gitconfig` these lines:

```
[include]
    path = .gitconfig
```

If you're using Vagrant as part of your code distribution, you may load git config from `Vagrantfile` by:

```
system('GIT_TRACE=1 git config --local include.path "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/git/gitconfig"');
```

then commit your git config in `git/gitconfig`, so each time when users run provisioning of their VM, this file would be loaded automatically for their git on host machine (e.g. to enforce `core.filemode` to be disabled, so *Windows* won't have any issues with file permissions).

---

To force line endings for users, you should use `.gitattributes` instead which should work out-of-box. Sample syntax to use Unix-like line endings (`LF`):

```
# Drupal git normalization
# @see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html
# @see https://www.drupal.org/node/1542048

# Define text file attributes.
# - Treat them as text.
# - Ensure no CRLF line-endings, neither on checkout nor on checkin.
# - Detect whitespace errors.
#   - Exposed by default in `git diff --color` on the CLI.
#   - Validate with `git diff --check`.
#   - Deny applying with `git apply --whitespace=error-all`.
#   - Fix automatically with `git apply --whitespace=fix`.

*.css     text eol=lf whitespace=blank-at-eol,-blank-at-eof,-space-before-tab,tab-in-indent,tabwidth=2
*.html    text eol=lf whitespace=blank-at-eol,-blank-at-eof,-space-before-tab,tab-in-indent,tabwidth=2 diff=html
*.js      text eol=lf whitespace=blank-at-eol,-blank-at-eof,-space-before-tab,tab-in-indent,tabwidth=2
*.json    text eol=lf whitespace=blank-at-eol,-blank-at-eof,-space-before-tab,tab-in-indent,tabwidth=2

# Auto-detect text files, ensure they use LF (not recommended).
#*         text=auto eol=lf

# Define binary file attributes.
# - Do not treat them as text.
# - Include binary diff in patches instead of "binary files differ."
*.gz      -text diff
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a better way to use the [hardlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link):

In *nix or OS X system:

```
ln .git/config git-config
git add git-config
git commit -m "Now tracking git config file"
```

In Windows on NTFS-filesystem System:

```
mklink /H git-config .git\config
git add git-config
git commit -m "Now tracking git config file"
```

But we must remember that when cloning project to apply the settings to perform the reverse procedure:

In *nix or OS X system:

```
git clone FROM_PROJ_URL
rm .git/config
ln git-config .git\config
```

In Windows on NTFS-filesystem System:

```
git clone FROM_PROJ_URL
del .git\config
mklink /H .git\config git-config
```

Comment: why would hardlink be better?