# How to get rid of bogus changes in git?

Tags: git, version-control, github, whitespace

I'm a happy user of PortableGit 1.7.0.2. Today I wanted to pull a project changes from GitHub.com repository, so I did `git pull`. It failed with the following message: `error: Your local changes to 'main.rb' would be overwritten by merge. Aborting.`. I didn't care about the local changes so I typed `git reset --hard HEAD` (`git clean` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull) didn't help neither), but it didn't work. When asked for `git status` I was still able to see the file as modified. `git diff` showed me that each line of the file has been modified, while `git diff -b` showed no differences at all, so I guess this is a line ending issue. Which is strange because the code is only pushed from Windows machines.

Anyway, the question is: how can I ignore the local, bogus changes and merge with the latest changes from the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, did you try a `git clean -f` (note the '`-f`')?
From [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page:

```
clean.requireForce
```

> A boolean to make `git-clean` do nothing unless given `-f` or `-n`. **Defaults to true**.

Second, did you set your `autocrlf` setting to false [as I mention in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278)?
(even if pushed from a Windows machine to a Windows PC, a text file with Unix eol would be converted to Windows eol)

With those two points taken care of, you should be able to pull.

Comment: I did use the '-f', but haven't heard about 'autocrlf' before. The later did help, thanks VonC!