# git status shows modified after files copied

Tags: git, filesystems

When I copy files from my Linux machine to my external HDD (FAT format), 'git status' shows that files are modified. I guess that occurs because of the file system difference.

I formatted the external HDD with FAT to share it with my Mac, Windows, and Linux.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Which filesystem is the repository on? What happens if you use `git diff` to show the modifications of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be caused by mismatched permission bits. From [git-config manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> core.fileMode
>
> If false, the executable bit
>   differences between the index and the
>   working copy are ignored; useful on
>   broken filesystems like FAT. See
>   git-update-index(1).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set your [`core.autocrlf` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278).
The eol (end of line) style can vary between OS/supports and introduce those "changes".

Answer (score 1):

When you're copying files, if you're physically moving the bits from one disk to another (like with cp or drag and dropping), then you might consider creating a bare repo on your external drive to push/pull from on your other systems.

It doesn't address the EOL changes that need to be made ( mentioned in VonC's response for example), but it does save a little time copying files back and forth between drives.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be, if you are sure that there is no changes between the 2 folders, to checkout and pull

```
git checkout -- .
git pull
```