# Git files changed after clean checkout

Tags: git

I did `git checkout master`. If I do `git status` it shows two changed files in my working directory, even though I haven't touched them. It appears to be some sort of line ending issue.

`git reset --hard HEAD` doesn't help too.

I have set `core.ignorecase=true`, doesn't help.

What's wrong here? Git on Windows is still bugging me like hell...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you set **`core.autocrlf`** to false (especially on Windows)?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278) for good reason to leave it to false.

Other causes could include a [`.gitattribute` filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) which would perform some changes on file content.

Comment: hell yeah, the autorclf did the trick. Seems to be enabled by default and everyone else on the net recommends turning it on (that's what I did trying to fix my problems and it didn't work).

Comment: @Johannes: "everyone else on the net recommends turning it on"?? If so, I am definitively *not* in that camp ;)

Comment: Github is in this camp though (just recently discovered) http://help.github.com/dealing-with-lineendings/

Comment: @Johannes: well, GitHub mentions setting it to '`input`', not 'true', forcing 'lf' to all files. I still maintain a "no automatic conversion of any kind" policy though ;)

Comment: GitHub advocates `input`for MacOs and Linux, for Windows they're all in for autorclf, which I don't like too :-)