# git pull and fetch fail with "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, cygwin

From cygwin git on Win7 I'm trying to coordinate with my linux workstation. Both were cloned from the same upstream repository. First I do a "git fetch origin", then try to fetch from my workstation.

```
$ git fetch origin
[... all ok ...]
$ git fetch b
scheib@b's password:
remote: Counting objects: 2031, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (512/512), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOFs:  23% (182/789)
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750222/cygwin-git-clone-gives-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-against-ubuntu-10-04-1 help? (including using msysgit instead of cygwin git?)

Comment: I've worked around this by using msysgit and ssh protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's ssh.exe has this bug. Replace cygwin's ssh.exe with ssh.exe from a msysgit install, and this problem will go away.

Related: [Git fatal: remote end hung up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493645/git-fatal-remote-end-hung-up)

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a quest/answer format, not a threaded conversation format. Every "answer" should *be* an answer.

Comment: Yes, better. Moreover looking at the edit history I was probably too harsh n the first place. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

How did you create your keys?

With cygwin's git or with the mingw git in git bash?

I believe the real problem is that cygwin's ssh looks for .ssh in /home/*name*/.ssh and mingw's git ssh looks for .ssh in c:/user/*name*/.ssh

Chances are your keys are in one and only one of these directories.

You can trying telling cygwin's .ssh to use  a different identity file using the -i switch, or move the keys into both directories, or create an ssh config file in /home/*name*/.ssh/config.

I created a config that contains:

```
Host github.com
    User jerryasher
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile c:/Users/jerry/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And given that I can use either the mingw git from git bash or cygwin's git from an rxvt to interact with github.

Comment: It wouldn't connect if the keys were the issue