# Git-svn rebase with local changes

Tags: git, git-svn

According to the `git-svn` [manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) about `git svn rebase`:

> If you have local changes, you must either stash your work or temporarily commit it before running git svn rebase — otherwise, the command will stop **if it sees that the rebase will result in a merge conflict**

However every time I git rebase, I always get the `needs update` error message with any locally modified file, even if it would not conflict with incoming changes:

```
> git svn rebase
path/to/file.txt: needs update
```

I'm using `git-svn version 2.15.0.windows.1 (svn 1.9.7)`. Is the manual out of date, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, unfortunately it is **not possible**.
From the documentation of [git svn 2.38.1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn/2.38.1%60):
`Like git rebase; this requires that the working tree be clean and have no uncommitted changes.`
So, you have to stash and pop before using git svn rebase.

But I think there is a problem with this command, because the documentation says: `This accepts all options that git svn fetch and git rebase accept`, normally git rebase accepts `--autostash` option.

```
> git rebase -h
   .
   .
   --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after
   .
```

but git svn rebase does not accept autostash option.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that [even for a simple `git pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6263894/6309)

Check your `git config core.autocrlf`, and make sure it is set to `false`: that way, you won't have any automatic eol (end of line) modification on checkout (which is the first operation of a rebase)

Comment: It still won't work. I rebased with `git svn rebase` and after that I changed a file locally. even though there is no other change in svn repository, I am unable to run `git svn rebase` 

> `git config core.autocrlf`
true
> `git config core.autocrlf false`
> `git svn rebase`                
testfile.txt: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
# I reverted the local changes here
> `git svn rebase`
Current branch master is up to date.

Comment: @Sahin Try the same `git svn init` (full new clone/import) *after* `git config --global core.autocrlf false`