# How to fix windows line endings after git clone

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I have cloned a repository from github on a Windows 7 box, and made some of changes I would hate to lose. However, all my file have wrong line endings, \n instead of \r\n.

How should I fix it?

I think I should clone my repo again with correct line endings, and move over my changes manually.

How do I clone it properly, so that  all line ending are \r\n?

Are there any better suggestions?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't clone the repository with a different style of line endings.  The data in the repository is what it is.  What you can do is tell git how you want to handle the line endings when checking in or out.  The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278) that birryree pointed out in the comments is a good source.   There is also [Github's](http://help.github.com/line-endings/) help page on it.

Depending on what you are editing, you can also use a Windows text editor that doesn't require crlf, like [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  You can change the line endings that notepad++ uses by default in `settings->preferences->New Document/Default Directory`

To add from Charles' comment, you can also convert line endings to unix or windows style in notepad++. You do this by going to `edit->EOL Conversion`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to run the `dos2unix` win32 utility found [here](http://www.bastet.com/).

Info: `dos2unix.exe` converts MS-DOS text files to Unix format, by stripping any `CR` or end-of-file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) characters from the data.