# What does the error "EGit could not detect where Git is installed" mean?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

What does this error mean and how to resolve it? I am new to eclipse and I downloaded eclipse from a ftp from Japan and I don't know if I have downloaded all the necessary files.

Have I missed anything?

[image: pic here]

Comment: thanks daniel, i couldnt add the pic here due to insuff rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with Eclipse4.2 and EGit2.3, this warning will be more discrete and less "in your face": see [bug 391377](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391377).

Otherwise, this warning reminds you of setting how the eol (end of lines) should be treated when Egit checkout files on your computer.
The goal would be to avoid "**[The Wall of Pink](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx)**".

(I prefer setting [`core.autocrl` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278), personally)

---

The [OP elle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983088/elle) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996278/eclipse-git-error/14996788#comment21064707_14996788) the possibility to quiet those warning in the settings:

```
window>preferences>team>git>confirmation dialogues
```

Comment: i have resolved this by unchecking home directory warning and git prefix warning from window>preferences>team>git>confirmation dialogues

Comment: @elle good catch. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error.  Do not panic.

It is merely a warning that if you are using the command line Git as well, eGit can't figure out the defaults for that setup so that it can match them automatically.  If you're not using command-line Git, just check the check box and move on.