# How to make EGit use the same global settings as native git

Tags: eclipse, git, cygwin, egit

I've just migrated my development environment to a new PC. For this, I copied both my Eclipse workspace and my Cygwin home directory, so that I don't have to set up my global git settings again. This worked fine for native git – all global settings are there – but not for EGit which doesn't see the global settings.

I vaguely remember that EGit does some [magic to automatically detect the native git settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996278/what-does-the-error-egit-could-not-detect-where-git-is-installed-mean), but apparently that magic is not working.

So how can I (manually) configure EGit to also use the global settings from native git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer in the [EGit documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Setting_up_the_Home_Directory_on_Windows): The `HOME` environment variable needs to be configured to point to the Cygwin user home.

Then, EGit will read the native settings as "User Settings":

[image]