# how do I keep git config entries across pulls

Tags: git, diff, configuration-files

I have a git repo and I'd like to set a config entry so that anyone who pulls gets that config entry.

The specifics are that I have a sqlite3 database in the repo, and I'd like to configure git diff to show text versions of the database.

I have a .gitattributes file in the repo that makes git use the diff "sqlite3":

```
*.sqlite3 diff=sqlite3
```

but the sqlite3 diff needs to be defined in a git config section, like so:

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    binary = true
    textconv = "echo .dump | sqlite3"
```

Currently I have tried putting it in the .git/config file, but it is not defined when pulling from this repo.

A workaround is to put it in the .git/config or ~/.gitconfig of each user, but I'd like it to be automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code

Comment: the answer to that question doesn't address the fundamental question of of distributing git configuration.  That question mentions using a `.gitattributes` file, which I also mentioned in my question, but does not discuss `.git/config` (even though that was what was asked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those users have access to a common shared folder, you can take advantage of a **[template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.html#_template_directory)** use in [`git init --template=...`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.html).

That template directory can contain a `config` file which would be copied during the initialization of the repo by a user.

Other than that, a config isn't shared between repos instances.

---

The alternative is to version a script which can execute the appropriate `git config` commands you want your users to run.
And have a `README` explicit enough to clearly indicate the users of your rpeo they should run said script.