# Why couldn't I discard a file from my working directory in Git?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

I have a modified file in a Git working directory which I want to discard.
This file is ***not*** in a submodule.

I tried 3 different commands and nothing helped.

1. `git checkout -- <file>`, `or git checkout <file>`
2. `git reset HEAD --hard`
3. `git stash save --keep-index`

How to discard that file?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try `git checkout <full-path-of-file-you-want-to-discard>`?

Comment: I did short and it gave me no error. And didn't discard as you saw on screenshot

Comment: Are any changes shown by `git diff` ?

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf false` try doing this.

Comment: I have this option set to true intentionally because of cross-platform team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you set `git config --global core.autocrlf true`, you will see changes applied automatically to those file.

I would recommend:

- setting [`core.autocrlf` to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)
- adding a `core.eol` directive in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for the specific files or types of files you want to be handled (in term of EOL style).